# Vibrate using UIFeedbackGenerator or AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

Tags: ios, uifeedbackgenerator

When I want an iPhone to vibrate, how can I determine whether to use `UIFeedbackGenerator` or `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`?

The new haptic engine is only available on iOS10 and on the iPhone 7 models, so how would we write code that uses this new engine when supported, but falls back to using the not as cool `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` when not?

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) to not worry about it, and that `UIFeedbackGenerator` simply won't do anything if not supported, but I don't see how this help me if I still want it to vibrate since its methods do not have any kind of success callback.

> Note that calling these methods does not play haptics directly.
> Instead, it informs the system of the event. The system then
> determines whether to play the haptics based on the device, the
> application’s state, the amount of battery power remaining, and other
> factors.
>
> For example, haptic feedback is currently played only:
>
> - On a device with a supported Taptic Engine (iPhone 7 and iPhone 7
>   Plus).
> - When the app is running in the foreground.
> - When the System Haptics setting is enabled.
>
> As a general rule, trust the system to determine whether it should
> play feedback. Don't check the device type or app state to
> conditionally trigger feedback. After you’ve decided how you want to
> use feedback, always trigger it when the appropriate events occur. The
> system ignores any requests that it cannot fulfill.

Comment: `init` the `UIFeedbackGenerator` object, if the object is `nil` then you are not on the preferred engine, fallback to `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)`.

Comment: I thought UIFeedbackGenerator is a part of iOS10, and can, therefore, be initiated no matter what device you are on?

Comment: In your question it reads `only available on iOS10` **and** `on the iPhone 7 models,`

Comment: The haptic engine, yes. The UIFeedbackGenerator is a part of UIKit on iOS10, so from what I understand, you can still try to use it. I just won't have any effect unless coupled with a newer device.

Comment: Yeah, but the hardware has to support those API's right. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator

Comment: In the link you posted: "At this time, only the new Taptic Engine found in the iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus support these APIs. Other devices silently ignore the haptic requests." The fact that other devices silently ignores the requests makes me believe that initiating an object would still work

Comment: Sorry I lost track what was the question, use https://gist.github.com/imkevinxu/2bb1197552b095ab25c8 to check if the device is `iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus` along with `available API for iOS 10`... If not use the `AudioServices API`